# Laravel orWhere query incredibly slow even with index

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

My Laravel 8 API has a search feature allowing a user to search for something in any given column in my database, all of my columns, of which are just a handful have an index on them to make them efficient at pulling results, however, my search filter appears to be incredibly slow at searching 4 million records whilst simply getting the 4 million is done in just a few seconds.

I'm trying to figure out why it's so slow since they've all got an index on them, what could I be missing?

Below is my function and query, and if `$search` isn't empty then I'm using various `orWhere` methods since the `$search` needs to check each of these columns so that the user in my front-end doesn't have to choose the column to search for.

```php
/**
 * Applications
 */
public function getApplications($options)
{

    $perPage = $options['per_page'] ?? 25;
    $search = (isset($options['search']) && !empty($options['search'])) ? htmlspecialchars($options['search']) : '';
    $search = strtolower($search);

    if ($search != '') {
      $applications = Application::where('hash', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                                 ->orWhere('mobile', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                                 ->orWhere('postcode', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                                 ->orWhere('birthday', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                                 ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                                 ->orWhere('product_type', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                                 ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                                 ->paginate((int) $perPage);

      $applications->onEachSide(1);
    } else {
      $applications = Application::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                                 ->paginate((int) $perPage);

      $applications->onEachSide(1);
    }



    foreach ($applications as $key => $applicant) {
      try {
        $applications[$key]['data'] = json_decode($applicant['data']);
      } catch (\Exception $e) { }
    }

    return $applications;

}
```

I've limited my front-end to 2 minutes for the request, and it's reaching that!

Comment: a query of the form `LIKE %...%` cannot use a normal text index. You should look into [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) (Link is MySQL but there are alternatives) or use an app specialised for this purpose like elasticsearch

Comment: Ahh... right, I didn't know that, that's incredibly annoying and I doubt the Laravel query builder has a simple workaround for this?

Comment: try to explain query then add result to question

Comment: For instance, what can I change `->orWhere('mobile', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')` to make this faster and use the index

Comment: This is a query issue (use `EXPLAIN [query]` to see how the query optimizer sees it). You could firehose all the rows and implement `array_filter()` to perform the search on what comes back using `stripos() !== false`, if the lag in performance is acceptable (reading the whole 4m rows seems bad if it's too often), or implement full text with `MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)`.

Comment: If you really want indexes and know what all the search terms would be, you could pre-search and match applications against the search term, then simply lookup and match on the search term and the found `id`'s. This would use the indexes and be quite fast, but you would need to know all the search terms or do the search and store the references before hand, and if new applications are added, keep the list updated.

Comment: the only way you can use a normal text index with a wildcard query is if it's a prefix query e.g. `orWhere('mobile', 'like', "$search%")` which (since indexes are usually sorted) can do a simple binary search to find results however a `"%$search%"` type query has to scan all rows  and there is no way to optimise this. A full text index works differently by splitting text into tokens and indexing them but is not ideal because then you're searching for tokens and even that is not a true wildcard search

Comment: @apokryfos I've just tried a prefix query as per your comment, it appears that it's still incredibly slow whereas an exact match with `whereIn` appears to be super fast, so I don't think prefix query is using indexes